# Windows phone 8.1 pretend to be a bluetooth device with iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, windows-phone-8, bluetooth

I'm trying to port a bluetooth app that connects with a health device from iPhone to Windows phone. I have no idea how the data is sent, so I had the idea of changing the device id to match the health device in order to see what data is sent. However, I've run into a small hurdle. I can request a connection from the windows phone to the iPhone, and they connect. However, when I attempt to connect from the iPhone to the Windows phone, it says that "the device is not supported", and forgets the device. I guess there are two questions here.

A) Is what I am doing possible? If so, how?

B) If not, is there a way to do what I am trying?

Thanks!

Comment: Use an app light LightBlue on the iPhone to examine the BLE services and characteristics from your device

Comment: Sadly, the blood pressure device doesn't use BLE, it uses Bluetooth 2.0 I believe. Anything else you can recommend that can log activity?

Comment: If it is BT 2.0 then you might be better off trying to connect using a Bluetooth stack on Windows or Mac OSX.

Comment: Ok, I can connect. Any way I can view from the Mac or Windows what data it has received? Or should I write something?

Comment: If it is bluetooth 2.0 then it probably uses a serial port profile. You may be able to use a terminal program or you may need to write some code. Reverse engineering is a bit of an art